# How to block empty user agent

Tags: apache-httpd, bandwidth, htaccess

I'm using CentOS 7 on my server, and Apache2 as my web server.

In AWStats in my Cpanel, I could see that I've a large bandwidth used by a bot called "empty user agent string" (see the pic attached). How could I block him to avoid bandwidth loss?

I already used the code below in `.htaccess` but it seems not to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I would look into a tool called [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  This tool can be configured to watch your apache logs for suspicious behaviour and then adapt firewall rules to block the malicious IPs.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.htaccess` should block empty user agents and user agents with name `-`. Make sure you allow `.htaccess` overrides in your global apache config (`AllowOverride All`<sup>1</sup> to allow all overrides or `AllowOverride FileInfo`<sup>2</sup> to only allow the rewrite rules in the matching `Directory` block) and don't forget to enable the rewrite engine with `RewriteEngine On`.

It also doesn't hurt if you add the [last flag `L`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) to your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

1. [AllowOverride Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
2. [AllowOverride FileInfo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/overrides.html#override-fileinfo)

Comment: Ok, I woud try.

Comment: I already tried and nothing happened, also it block my server and I couldn't acces to my websites till I removed those lines you shown me